Manual feature selection and hyperparameter tuning
For a very small dataset that I have, when I set the parameters with the help of gridsearch, the test and training results are not acceptable at all and have a huge difference. I have to manually select the parameters! In addition, I do feature selection for each model separately with the help of rfe and I also select this item manually. Is there a way to find both the desired parameters and the number of features more quickly?
The dataset has 65 samples and 20 features, which I have selected with the help of RFE. The problem is also regression.
